# How to change Compiled->False to Method->{Compiled->False} in multiple notebooks?

Tags: notebooks

I have a collection of about 40 notebooks where the options for ParametricPlot and ParametricPlot3D have:

```
Compiled->False
```

and I need to switch any/all instances to

```
Method->{Compiled->False}
```

Is there a way to do this via Mathematica v.9? One challenge is that I do not know all the notebooks which may or may not have this.

Perhaps Mathematica is not the proper tool and this is more of shell scripting exercise?

Any thoughts on the best way to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

t.

PS - Mac OS X, Mathematica v.9 (latest update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how robust this is, but if `old.nb` is the old notebook,

```
Export["~/Desktop/new.nb",
 Import["/Users/acl/Desktop/old.nb"] /. 
  RowBox[{"Compiled", "\[Rule]", "False"}] :> 
   RowBox[{"Method", "\[Rule]", 
     RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"Compiled", "\[Rule]", "False"}], "}"}]}]
 ]
```

does what you want and saves it to `new.nb`.

You can go through all notebooks by mapping this over `Filenames[]` (ask if you don't know how).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll check the documentation on Filenames[] and I should be able to run with it from here. I wouldn't have noticed the "\[Rule]" markup unless you pointed that out. Sometimes it's nice to just use emacs to view the notebooks and see what's actually written!

Comment: @user7040 if you use emacs, why not just use that? do you know elisp? but this may be easier... The idea about `FileNames` is to do something like `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];FileNames["*.nb"]` to obtain a list of notebook files, then maybe assign the code I gave above to a function and map that. Ask here if you have problems.